# copy of memory stream error

Tags: c#, stream, httpwebrequest, memorystream

I have a problem copying data from MemoryStream into Request Stream.

```
var Request = (HttpWebRequest.Create(Url) as HttpWebRequest);
Request.Method = "PUT";
Stream RequestStream = Request.GetRequestStream();

// write to MemoryStream
var MemStream = new MemoryStream();
byte[] Test = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test000\r\n");
MemStream.Write(Test, 0, Test.Length);

// test writing correctly
byte[] B = MemStream.ToArray();
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(B)); // shows data correctly

// copy data to request stream(not working!)
MemStream.CopyTo(RequestStream);

// add new data to request stream(working)
byte[] Test1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test111");
RequestStream.Write(Test1, 0, Test1.Length);
```

Sent to the server only "test111". Got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy to copies the data from current position. so it fails to copy as position is at end. where as `ToArray` returns all data irrespective of position.

> Copying begins at the current position in the current stream, and does not reset the position of the destination stream after the copy operation is complete.

Try this

```
MemStream.Position = 0;
MemStream.CopyTo(RequestStream);
```

Refer [Stream.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) for more info

Comment: thank you, I know how to accept answer. but less than 10 minutes, it can not be accepted

Answer (score 1):

The position of the memstream is at the end. because of the `MemStream.Write(Test, 0, Test.Length);`

use:

```
// copy data to request stream(would work!)
MemStream.Position = 0;
MemStream.CopyTo(RequestStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

Set MemoryStream object Position=0 and use CopyTo method

MemStream.Position = 0;
MemStream.CopyTo(RequestStream);